# Join and order columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Example:

```
a    b    p.a    p.b
1    2    x      y
3    4    c      d
2    1    y      x
5    6    f      e
1    1    x      x
```

I would like to join `p.a` and `p.b` (property of `a` and `b`) so that if there occurs a pair of `a` and `b` all pairs of `b` and `a` should be turned around to be pairs of `a` and `b` and the order of the properties should be preserved and then joined into a new column. So only if the first two column change, the last two columns also should change. I know that I can use `paste` to join two columns but I'm not sure how to get the order of the column entries right.

The result should be as follows:

```
a    b    p.a    p.b    joined
1    2    x      y      xy
3    4    c      d      cd
1    2    x      y      xy
5    6    f      e      fe
1    1    x      x      xx
```

It is not important, whether the rows for `a` and `b` are `1    2` or `2    1`, but if there is `1    2` there should be no `2    1` and vice versa

Comment: You really need data which presents the possible variations; what you have could be solved with `paste0`, but that doesn't sound like the logic you need.

Comment: I think that is about all that there can be. Except that I have more elements than 1,2,3,4 and c,d,x,y. The solution by @akrun seems like it is what I need.

Comment: @alistaire If you don't know how I would like to handle certain cases, which ones would that be? I'd like to complete the tables to make it clearer.

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted, but it is hard to get the key point from your question. Is my interpretation right: "I want to join two comlumns containing `x,c` and `y,d`. how can I join these two to get a column  with well defined order, that is only `xy` and `cd` occur (no `yx` and `dc)`. What about `xx`, ...?

Comment: For `1,1` the properties will always be the same. You would have something like `1    1    c    c`. So there is no point in changing the positions of `1,1` or `c,c` and `c,c` can be merged just like that. But yes, your interpretation seems right.

Comment: Added some more rows to make it clearer

Comment: One possible reason for downvoting is failure to provide an unambiguous example. The console result of print does not convey the classo of a column so the p.a and p.b could be either character or factor. This is important to know in construction an effective answer. You should learn to use `dput` as suggested in the canoncal answers to a question titles something along the lines of "How to make a great question about R"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the updated dataset, we can loop through the rows, get the `order` based on the 1st two column elements, and `order` the columns based on that.

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(i) {
               x1 <- df1[i,]
               i1 <- order(unlist(x1[1:2]))
               x1[1:2] <- unlist(x1[1:2])[i1]
               x1[3:4] <- unlist(x1[3:4])[i1]
               x1}))

df2$joined <- do.call(paste0, df2[3:4]) 
df2
#  a b p.a p.b joined
#1 1 2   x   y     xy
#2 3 4   c   d     cd
#3 1 2   x   y     xy
#4 5 6   f   e     fe
#5 1 1   x   x     xx
```

Comment: Ok so there is the problem, looking at your first solution: the third and the fourth column should only change if the first and the second column change. As far as I see `a,b` and `p.a,p.b` are just changed alphabetically. But `p.a` and `p.b` are properties of `a` and `b`. So in case of `1 2 y x` it would change to `1 2 x y`, right?

Comment: @doc I updated the solution with your new dataset.  Upon apply the second solution, I get the expected output

Comment: No, line 4 is different. The output should be `5    6    f      e      fe` because `f e` only changes if `5 6` changes. `5 6` however does not change and so should not `f e`

Comment: @doc Corrected the output with a new solution